# Want to validate image raw data using php

Tags: php, image

I want to validate whether the image raw data is valid or not.

Below is my code :

```
private function __blobToImage($imagerawdata)
{       
    $imagedata = base64_decode($imagerawdata);
    // Set the content type header - in this case image/jpeg
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

    $path = WWW_ROOT . "commapp_images".'/';
    $file = mktime().".png";
    $filepath = $path.$file;

    // Output the image     
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imagedata); 
    ob_start(); 
    imagejpeg($image, $filepath, 80);
    ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $file;
}
```

While using my code I'm getting the below error

```
"Notice (8): imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file"
```

Any one please help me as because I strucked here with out any solution.

Comment: Where is the encoded data ($imagerawdata) come from?

Answer (score 1):

[`imagecreatefromstring`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) already does that, it returns `false` on failure. So you could suppress it's message and check for the return value:

```
$image = @imagecreatefromstring($imagedata);
if ($image !== false)
{
  ...
}
```

**Edit:** You don't need the `header` and output buffering if you are saving to a file and you are saving a jpeg with the png extension.

Comment: Hi, I'm always getting success but the image is saving as blank image. But it is throwing the error as "Notice (8): imagecreatefromstring() [function.imagecreatefromstring]: gd-jpeg, libjpeg: recoverable error: Premature end of JPEG file"

Comment: @VineelaYarlagadda Not sure if it is related, but you are saving a jpeg as a png file. You should change the extension or the function you are calling.